# Opencv print text with outline

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, image-masking

I would like to render a custom text on an image using opencv, while having a white outline around the text, with the inside of the text being black. Currently I am only able to print the text in a single static color (black in this case) like so:

```
cv2.putText(img, "My text", (x, y), font, font_size, (0, 0, 0), font_thickness, lineType = cv2.LINE_AA)
```

How can I achieve an effect like the one shown below, where the outline of the text is printed in white, and the inner part in black?

[image]

Note: The text is placed on an image, so the remaining space (the grey space in the example image) around the text should be transparent.

Comment: dont abuse a computer-vision library for "effects", please.

Comment: Excuse me? I am not abusing the library for special effects, I simply like to increase the visibility over the overlayed text, no point in adding additional dependencies for such a minor thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could draw the text twice on the image: one for your outline and the other for your text.

```
cv2.putText(image,"text",(180,150),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,3,(255,255,255),16,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(image,"text",(180,150),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,3,(0,0,0),4,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

[image]